# focus() method not working on revealed element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, click, focus

On a static website, the main navigation is hidden on small screens and revealed when a hamburger icon is clicked.  When revealed, I want the tab focus to be removed from the hamburger icon and set to the first menu item. I've tried various solutions found here, like using setTimeout, but nothing has worked.

```
<div class="header__item header__logo">
  <div class="header__icon header__icon--mobileTrigger">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" aria-label="open menu">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header__item header__nav" aria-label="main menu">
  <nav role="navigation" class="nav__wrapper">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
      <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
        <li><a href="#started" id="menu-focus" tabindex="0">Let's get started</a></li>
        <li><a href="#solutions" aria-current="false">More solutions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".header__icon--mobileTrigger", function (e) {
      $(this).find(".hamburger").addClass("is-active").attr("aria-label", "close menu");
      $(".header__nav").attr({
          role:"dialog", 
          "aria-modal":"true",
          tabindex:"-1"
      });
      $("#menu-focus").focus();
  });

document.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  console.log('focused: ', document.activeElement)
}, true);

</script>
```

I've tried blur() on the hamburger icon, various tab values, setTimeout functions, query selector, I even tried hard-coding the role and other attributes on the nav instead of relying on the programmatic method. I have also looked for a function that might be overriding mine.

Comment: I also tried to follow the instructions here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_role%3Ddialog_to_implement_a_modal_dialog_box

Comment: I tried your code and it worked without modification for me.  What do you expect to see when the link has the focus?

Comment: @Yogi Usually, to determine where focus is currently, I hit the shift key which exposes a blue outline around the element.  In my case, the blue outline shows up around the hamburger icon.  Another way to test this is to hit the tab key to see which element comes up next.  In my case, this also indicates the hamburger icon as the focus.

Comment: I created a codepen where it does indeed work! so there must be something else in the actual code that is interfering.  Please DM me if you are interested in looking at the staging site. 

https://codepen.io/avaljynn/pen/rNKQgPY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to lengthen the duration of the setTimeout.  Maybe because of the animations? I am not sure.  This worked:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#menu-focus").focus();
},300);
```